# Issue On Adding Slide Function on Bootstrap 3 Button Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/br0jkp1u/) and let me know why I am not able to add slide function to the Bootstrap 3 button dropdown?

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>

  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });

  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All dropdown events are fired at the .dropdown-menu's parent element. [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

You need to use

```
$('.btn-group').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() { ... });
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br0jkp1u/4/).

Answer (score 1):

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/br0jkp1u/6/

```
  $('#example').on('click', function () {
      $('ul.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
  });

 <button id="example" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/br0jkp1u/7/

```
[Fiddle][1]
```